# Spring Boot test class having dependency on external class inside jar

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm writing Junit test cases for my `spring boot` microservice project using `mockito` and `junit`, While running test cases as `Junit` all test cases are passed but while doing a `mvn test` compile fails because of spring not able to find test class dependency on common jar classes

I have tried few things but not able to find a way to mock/inject a class inside jar in my test class. `mvn test` always throws `NoClassDefFoundError` for the class which is inside some common jar included in project through `pom.xml`

**My test case**

```
@Test
public void AbcTest() throws Exception {
    JsonNode node1=objectMapper.readTree(appendPayload);
    JsonNode node2=objectMapper.readTree(appendPayload);
    AppendResult appendResult=new AppendResult(node1, node2));
    when(service.appendMessage(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(appendResult);
    mockMvc.perform(post("/{id}/abc","XYZ")
    .contentType("application/json")
    .content(payload))
    .andExpect(status().isNoContent())
    .andDo(print());
   verify(service,times(1)).appendMessage(any(), any(), any());
}
```

Here Append resultis inside the common jar(which is included in this project)

** annotation above class **

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest({Controller.class,ABCService.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.commons")
public class EntityControllerTest {
    ....
    ....
}
```

here i also tried

```
@EntityScan("[package path in commons jar]")
```

so guys any help,what i am doing wrong?

Comment: try adding `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: @want2learn, thanks for your suggestion although it doesn't help me completely but  provided me with some direction.